# adodb setConnectionParameter CharacterSet

Tags: utf-8, adodb-php, character-set

How do you use the following code in adodb?

Where to put "'CharacterSet ',' UTF-8'"?

protected $connectionParameters = array();

```
/**
* Adds a parameter to the connection string.
*
* These parameters are added to the connection string when connecting,
* if the driver is coded to use it.
*
* @param    string  $parameter  The name of the parameter to set
* @param    string  $value      The value of the parameter
*
* @return null
*
* @example, for mssqlnative driver ('CharacterSet','UTF-8')
*/

    final public function setConnectionParameter($parameter,$value)
{

    $this->connectionParameters[$parameter] = $value;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

set it after you create the ADOdb object, but before you connection to the database.

```
$db = newADOConnection('mssqlnative');
$db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet', 'UTF-8');
$db->connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
```

Comment: (Watch the typos -- `ChearaterSet` should be `CharacterSet`, and `UTF8` may need to be `UTF-8`.)

Answer (score 0):

'CharacterSet' will not work for mysqli.

Correct one:

```
$db->setConnectionParameter(MYSQLI_SET_CHARSET_NAME, 'utf8');
```